# On iOS, prevent scrolling past content (make it like Android)

Tags: html, css, ios, scroll

I have a position:fixed container with content that I can scroll to view. On iOS, I'm able to scroll past the content, getting a peek at the container beneath the contents. This does not happen on Android. Can I make iOS behave like Android?

On iOS, I can scroll to see the yellow container background. I cannot on Android:

https://jsfiddle.net/45enwzdf/1/

```
<div id = "container">
    <div id="contents">
    start
    </div>
</div>

#container{
  position:fixed;
  height:100px;
  width:200px;
  background:yellow;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border:1px black solid;
}

#contents{
  height:1000px;
  width:200px;
  background:green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding => overscroll-behavior: none;

```
#container{
  position:fixed;
  height:100px;
  width:200px;
  background:yellow;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border:1px black solid;
  overscroll-behavior: none;
}
```

Comment: I tried this http://jsfiddle.net/Lpmaw0xf on iOS and the yellow container still peeks through. I think overscroll has more to do with the parent itself scrolling, which is not what this is.